How can I move location or setup user special folders for multiple windows installations but the same user on a single machine?
How can I move or otherwise link Windows user special folders (Documents, Downloads, etc) such that multiple Windows installations on the same machine can share them seamslessly for all programs and the same user on both Windows installations (eg. Win 11 Pro, and Win 11 Insider Preview Dev). Moving folder locations with the Properties menu in Windows Explorer while running in the different Windows systems, does work, however git and some other software has issues as the new folder location or subfolders at that location may be owed by different user guids from each Windows installation.
The folder in the new location does not appear in a "dir" command in the C:\Users\Mike directory (for me, Mike) in either cmd or pwsh shells; but it does show in windows explorer in the same location (C:\Users\Mike). Is a junction to the new location (moved by using the properties menu of the special folder) warranted (eg. using MKLINK /J in cmd.exe) to solve the above, or does this have unintended consequences?

"such that multiple Windows installations on the same machine can share them seamslessly" - You cannot.  Every user is machine specific, which means a user with the same username on multiple machines or installations, will be unique to each instalaltion or machine.  There is no way to share directories within user's profile with multiple users.  My suggestion is get away from saving files into the Documents and Downloads directory if you want to share a single directory with multiple users.
